# Weird behaviour of IMG TAG

Tags: css

I have an IMG element on my page. I set the height and width to 100% so IMG tag should cover the page. However I have some space at the end of the image

Please see here: http://kekor.hostzi.com/

Dev tools screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/plvXZ.jpg

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    .balotelli { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    body {background-color: red; height: 100%}
    html {height: 100%}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="balotelli" src="balotelli.jpg" alt="ss" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should copy & paste relevant codes here.

Comment: The page you pasted is being blocked by my firewall as "Malicious website".

Comment: takes up the whole screen here, chrome 31 dev

Comment: Please see here screenshot from dev tools http://i.imgur.com/0TKkDDv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning up styles syntax and add position: absolute;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    .balotelli { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; }
     body {background-color: red; height: 100%;}
     html {height: 100%;}

     </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <img class="balotelli" src="http://kekor.hostzi.com/balotelli.jpg" alt="ss" />
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any margins on your page. Are you referring to the scrollbars?

To remove scrollbars, use this CSS on your page:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

You will also want to set your image to `block` element:

```
.balotelli {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I can see the red color of the body background. Please see here: http://i.imgur.com/vvebRJ1.jpg